# Using GAP to find coset representatives

Tags: group-theory, gap, finitely-generated, computational-algebra

Given a finitely generated group $G$ and a normal subgroup of finite index $K$, how can I use GAP to find a list of coset representatives, and also show that two coset representatives are equal?

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Regarding Shaun's comment: one way to improve your post would be to tell us that you checked the manual, and explain if [Chapter 39.7-2](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap39.html#X81002AA87DDBC02F) of it is relevant or not.

Comment: For example, entering in GAP `?Cosets` would navigate you right to the section mentioned by @user1729. See the [GAP Carpentries-style lesson](https://carpentries-incubator.github.io/gap-lesson/01-command-line/index.html) for more tips on using the GAP help system.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `FactorCosetAction(G,K)` to obtain the permutation action of G on the cosets of K and use images of elements (i.e. where do they map 1) under this homomorphism to identify cosets. Also `AsList(RightTransversal(g,k));` will give you coset representatives (for any subgroup, normal not required). PErformance of course will depend on the index of $K$.